# how to enable submit button on page load of textbox

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want enable my submit button when the textbox value greater than 0. this textbox not an editable item. this textbox automatically filled by some function.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function () {
            $('#searchInput').keyup(function () {
                if ($(this).val() > 0) {
                    //Check to see if there is any text entered
                    // If there is no text within the input ten disable the button
                    $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    //If there is text in the input, then enable the button
                    $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', false);
                }
            });
        }); 
    </script>

<input type='number' name='searchQuery' id='searchInput' />
            <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submitBtn' class='enableOnInput' disabled='disabled' />
```

Answer (score 0):

If the textbox is filled in by a script / function, it is very likely that the `keyup`-event won't fire.

Try to use [jquery's `change`-event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) instead.

But that really depends on *how* you change the content in the script...